# on click button, app crashes

Tags: android

oncreate:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    changingTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.changingTextView);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

---

the script:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {


        if(v.getId() == R.id.button1){
        PaintDrawable drawable = (PaintDrawable) button1.getBackground();
        int color = drawable.getPaint().getColor();
        if(color==Color.WHITE)
            changingTextView.setText("continue");
        else
            changingTextView.setText("gameOVER");   
        }
        if(v.getId() == R.id.button2){
            PaintDrawable drawable = (PaintDrawable) button2.getBackground();
            int color = drawable.getPaint().getColor();
            if(color==Color.WHITE)
            changingTextView.setText("continue");
        else
            changingTextView.setText("gameOVER");
    } 
        if(v.getId() == R.id.button3){
            PaintDrawable drawable = (PaintDrawable) button3.getBackground();
            int color = drawable.getPaint().getColor();
            if(color==Color.WHITE)
            changingTextView.setText("continue");
        else
            changingTextView.setText("gameOVER");
    }
```

[here is the complete code+logcat image](http://www.siz.co.il/my.php?i=mjxjyjwgoe2j.png)

---

main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.bluetap.FirstActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:minWidth="200dp"
    android:text="Press The White Button"
    android:textColor="@color/blue" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:minWidth="200dp"
    android:text="Press The White Button"
    android:textColor="@color/blue" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:minWidth="200dp"
    android:text="Press The White Button"
    android:textColor="@color/blue" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/changingTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="text"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

---

in Eclipse there is no error in this code but when im running the application you can see everything and everything is fine but when you press the button1/2/3, the app crashes.
can you help me find out why?
my app just need to recognize if the button background is white, if does, it will continue, if not, it will pause and say game over.

Comment: post your onCreate(), esp where you set the listeners

Comment: edited. added the oncreate

Comment: post your logcat  and complete code also.so that we ill figure out where the problem is :)

Comment: my logcat is empty i don't know how... im going to it and it doesn't show nothing. i added it anyway.

Comment: go to DDms->left panel->select your pkg name under your device,back to java screen and then check logcat.

Comment: and it will be better if you use switch case to check id rather than else-if.

Comment: my device isn't working, im using the android virtual device and also transfering the apk file from the bin folder to my lg g2, both crashes. 
Dev Carlsberg, which xml?

Comment: xml of layout -> main.xml , also, there's no logcat in the link mentioned in the question

Comment: i don't know how to get the logcat.. added the main.xml